# Split array byte string in Python

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I'm trying to split a string of bytes like this:

```
'\xf0\x9f\x98\x84 \xf0\x9f\x98\x83 \xf0\x9f\x98\x80 \xf0\x9f\x98\x8a \xe2\x98\xba \xf0\x9f\x98\x89 \xf0\x9f\x98\x8d \xf0\x9f\x98\x98 \xf0\x9f\x98\x9a \xf0\x9f\x98\x97 \xf0\x9f\x98\x99 \xf0\x9f\x98\x9c \xf0\x9f\x98\x9d \xf0\x9f\x98\x9b \xf0\x9f\x98\x81 \xf0\x9f\x98\x82 \xf0\x9f\x98\x85 \xf0\x9f\x98\x86 \xf0\x9f\x98\x8b \xf0\x9f\x98\x8e \xf0\x9f\x98\xac \xf0\x9f\x98\x87'
```

into something like this:

```
'\xf0\x9f\x98\x84', '\xf0\x9f\x98\x83', etc.
```

However, the `split()` method returns me something like this:

```
'xf0', 'x9f' 'x98' etc.
```

I tried `split(" ")`, but it does not seem to work. How do I achieve the above mentioned?

Comment: What "split" method are you using? It looks like it doesn't understand the `\x` escape sequence and is thinking the backslash just escapes the next character.

Comment: What code did you use that got you individual characters? You cannot ever get `'xf0'` from splitting that input; that's strings with 3 characters, an `x` followed by a 2-digit hexadecimal number. It sounds as if you treated the strings as sequences rather than splitting them, resulting in strings with just one character each (like `'\xf0'`, note the backslash).

Comment: ... Is it splitting on `\\`?

Comment: Use split(' ') instead of split(" ") to split by empty spaces.

Comment: @Boop: there is **no difference** between those two method calls. Both split on spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`str.split(' ')` or even just `str.split()` (split on arbitrary-width whitespace) works just fine on your input:

```
sample = '\xf0\x9f\x98\x84 \xf0\x9f\x98\x83 \xf0\x9f\x98\x80 \xf0\x9f\x98\x8a \xe2\x98\xba \xf0\x9f\x98\x89 \xf0\x9f\x98\x8d \xf0\x9f\x98\x98 \xf0\x9f\x98\x9a \xf0\x9f\x98\x97 \xf0\x9f\x98\x99 \xf0\x9f\x98\x9c \xf0\x9f\x98\x9d \xf0\x9f\x98\x9b \xf0\x9f\x98\x81 \xf0\x9f\x98\x82 \xf0\x9f\x98\x85 \xf0\x9f\x98\x86 \xf0\x9f\x98\x8b \xf0\x9f\x98\x8e \xf0\x9f\x98\xac \xf0\x9f\x98\x87'
parts = sample.split()
```

Demo:

```
>>> sample = '\xf0\x9f\x98\x84 \xf0\x9f\x98\x83 \xf0\x9f\x98\x80 \xf0\x9f\x98\x8a \xe2\x98\xba \xf0\x9f\x98\x89 \xf0\x9f\x98\x8d \xf0\x9f\x98\x98 \xf0\x9f\x98\x9a \xf0\x9f\x98\x97 \xf0\x9f\x98\x99 \xf0\x9f\x98\x9c \xf0\x9f\x98\x9d \xf0\x9f\x98\x9b \xf0\x9f\x98\x81 \xf0\x9f\x98\x82 \xf0\x9f\x98\x85 \xf0\x9f\x98\x86 \xf0\x9f\x98\x8b \xf0\x9f\x98\x8e \xf0\x9f\x98\xac \xf0\x9f\x98\x87'
>>> sample.split()
['\xf0\x9f\x98\x84', '\xf0\x9f\x98\x83', '\xf0\x9f\x98\x80', '\xf0\x9f\x98\x8a', '\xe2\x98\xba', '\xf0\x9f\x98\x89', '\xf0\x9f\x98\x8d', '\xf0\x9f\x98\x98', '\xf0\x9f\x98\x9a', '\xf0\x9f\x98\x97', '\xf0\x9f\x98\x99', '\xf0\x9f\x98\x9c', '\xf0\x9f\x98\x9d', '\xf0\x9f\x98\x9b', '\xf0\x9f\x98\x81', '\xf0\x9f\x98\x82', '\xf0\x9f\x98\x85', '\xf0\x9f\x98\x86', '\xf0\x9f\x98\x8b', '\xf0\x9f\x98\x8e', '\xf0\x9f\x98\xac', '\xf0\x9f\x98\x87']
```

However, if this is binary data, you need to be careful that there are no `\x20` bytes in those 4-byte values. It might be better to just produce chunks of 5 bytes from this, then remove the last byte:

```
for i in range(0, len(sample), 5):
    chunk = sample[i:i + 4]  # ignore the 5th byte, a space
```

Demo:

```
>>> for i in range(0, len(sample), 5):
...     chunk = sample[i:i + 4]  # ignore the 5th byte, a space
...     print chunk.decode('utf8')
...     if i == 20: break
... 




# On browsers that support it, those are various smiling emoji
```